# IONIC ios emulator not able to make http requests

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4

having an issue making a post request for ionic 5 on a ios emulator

if I do a request on an android emulator it works fine, but when I do on a IOS emulator I get this error msg

```
[console.log]: "POST call in error" {
   "headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
     "lazyUpdate": null,
     "headers": {}
   },
   "status": 0,
  "statusText": "Unknown Error",
  "url": " <my url>.json",
  "ok": false,
  "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
   "message": "Http failure response for  <my url>/access_token.json: 0 Unknown Error",
   "error": {
     "isTrusted": true
   }
 }
```

this is how I'm making my request, using  http-client in angular

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is your URL https?

Comment: @KumarBibek yes is it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it turns out the endpoints I was trying to hit had an expired SSL, which is a no go on IOS. Manage to fix up the ssl and now my app works on IOS, hopefully this help someone else

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an issue with either the server or the ATS configuration for your iOS project. To verify this, you could try to switch on "Allow Arbitrary Loads" in the Xcode project's Info.plist file.

[image]

Set this value to **"YES"** and check if it works.

You might not find this key in the "Info.plist" file. In that case, you will have to add this key setting.

Comment: I just checked the setting and its already set to yes

Comment: I'm thinking its an ssl issue because the endpoint i'm trying to hit has an expired ssl, a noob question here but ios apps cannot hit endpoints/urls where the ssl is expired?

Comment: Not sure whether you can work with expired certificates on iOS. Never tried that. The documents do not mention about settings that could switch off this validation.